# Displaying user created data on user login in mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, scaffolding

I am developing an website in ASP.NET MVC4 where multiple institutes are created by admin.
These Institutes are granted login credentials through which they enter the website.The Institutes create multiple courses and course schedules .

Now I want when the institute logs in again,the logged in institute must be able to see and edit only his created courses and course schedules.I dont want Institute to view the entire table data.I don't want to use membership provider of ASP.NET MVC. Also, is it possible with LINQ Queries?

My database contains seperate TABLES for institutes , courses and courseschedules.I have used ado.net data model.
I am new to MVC4 and dont know how to proceed.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When institute log in. Create a cookie or session to store its ID. 
Now when they try to access pages then filter the records on bases of IDS of institute.

Whenever institute creates any course or course schedule than have column in table with foreign key that stores institute ID. so that it can be easy to filter.

Comment: Sorry for replying late.I tried this session code earlier too,but dont know how to proceed with filtering.I had been using Linq queries to filter like matching the primary keys of institutes and courses tables.Kindly elaborate the filtering code in controllers and views.